# Windows network drives through ssh and powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, networking, ssh, windows-7

When I physically go to the computer and initiate a powershell session, I am able to cd into a mapped drive (Z:), and run programs which access it.

However when I initiate an ssh session, and try to `cd` or execute programs which access the drive it says the drive name doesn't exist, if I try and  map the drive with

`net use Z: \\192.168.36.3\c$\`

It will tell me it is already mapped.  Programs which access the full path `Login failure: unknown user name or bad password`.

If I try `cd \\192.168.36.3\c$\`, it will ask me for credentials, if I give my current user's credentials I will get

`System error 86  the specified network password is incorrect`

None of this happens when I walk up to the computer and run powershell.

The output of `$env:username` through ssh is the same for the physical session and the remote one, and it's a Windows 7 computer which I have installed BitVise ssh server, and before that freesshd.  I was able connect with both of them, but had the same problem with remote drives.

Is there something I have to do to get the same rights as I would physically?

EDIT: `Get-PSDrive` physically has the mapped drive, but `Get-PSDrive` through SSH does not.  Am I not the user I am physically, despite `$env:username` telling me I am?

Comment: Try `Get-PSDrive` and see if it's mapped

Comment: No sign of `Z:` in `Get-PSDrive`.  What is the difference between a mapped network drive and a remembered connection?

Comment: I'm not familiar with using SSH in conjunction with PowerShell, but I'd make sure the drive is there if you want to interact with it (`Get-Help -Name 'New-PSDrive'`)

Comment: Which version of PowerShell is the target on?  I'll write up a quick answer.

Comment: I think you need to look into PowerShell remoting rather than shh...

Comment: `PSVersionTable.PSVersion Major: 2 Minor 0 Build -1 Revision -1`

Comment: @JamesC. In most orgs, SSH is already enabled.  PSRemoting is often unheard of (working on enabling it in my current environment).

Answer (score 0):

So, while you're remoted in with SSH:

```
$Cred = New-Object -TypeName 'PSCredential' -ArgumentList (Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter Domain\Username'),(Read-Host -Prompt 'Password' -AsSecureString)
#Alt: $Cred = Get-Credential
#Alt2: $Cred = Get-Credential -Message 'Creds!' -UserName 'domain\user'
If (-not (Get-PSDrive -Name Z)) { New-PSDrive -Name Z -PSProvider FileSystem -Root '\\192.168.36.3\c$' -Credential $Cred }
```

The `If` block is a bit long, but I made it a one-liner so you can copy/paste to the terminal

Comment: Running this script gives me `New-Object : Cannot find type [PSCredential]: make sure the assembly containing this type is loaded.`

Comment: @icecream_hobbit Try replacing that with `$Cred=Get-Credential`.  Very weird as that's a native PS type.

Comment: Invoking `Get-Credential` produces `cmdlet Get-Credential at command pipeline position 1 
Supply values for the following parameters: Credential` And I have to restart the session.  Am I using the command wrong?

Comment: It should be prompting you.. It looks like it's taking the wrong parameter set.  Try: `Get-Credential -Message 'Enter Creds!' -UserName 'domain\user'` @icecream_hobbit

Comment: `A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Message'`  I think I should update powershell.  I wasn't eager to because the computer runs some arcane and very proprietary software, but I'll report back if that fixes my problem

Comment: @icecream_hobbit PowerShell is fully backwards-compatible, as an FYI

Comment: I can now create the credential object, but running the `New-PSDrive -Name Z -PSProvider FileSystem -Root '\\192.168.36.3\c$' -Credential $Cred` It still gives me `The specified network password is not correct`.